# Cant run python files on terminal in Mac

Tags: macos, python-2.7

Whenever I try python "x".py it says file can't be found

and when I try drag the file into terminal it says permission denied.

Comment: Try `ls *py` to see names of all Python scripts in current directory. Try `pwd` to check which directory you are in.

Comment: Also type 'which python' to check your path.

Comment: Try `python x.py` or set the executable bit: `chmod +x x.py`